# Writing a BMP with transparency using ImageIO

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, bmp

Does anyone have a way of storing a `BufferedImage` with transparency as BMP in Java? Preferably using the `ImageIO` API.

For some reason I can't write a BMP in ARGB (BGRA) format, even though [the BMP has supported alpha channel since, at least, Win95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_.28bitmap_information_header.29). I can, however, easily write the same image as a PNG. It also works fine storing an image without alpha, like `TYPE_INT_RGB` or `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (!ImageIO.write(new BufferedImage(300, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), "BMP", new File("foo.bmp"))) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't write BMP!");
    }
    if (!ImageIO.write(new BufferedImage(300, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), "PNG", new File("foo.png"))) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't write PNG!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Couldn't write BMP!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`BMPImageWriterSpi`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/com/sun/imageio/plugins/bmp/BMPImageWriterSpi.java#89):

```
public boolean canEncodeImage(ImageTypeSpecifier type) {
    ...
    if (!(numBands == 1 || numBands == 3))
        return false;
```

I'm afraid Java doesn't support 32 bit BMPs. You'd have to write your own or find an existing library (ImageJ comes to mind although I don't know if it supports BMP). Wikipedia is very elaborate on the file format and it looks quite easy, even giving a complete field-by-field example of a 32-bit BMP.

Comment: Thanks! I found that too, which is quite disappointing... I'll probably just write my own BMP plugin. The format is quite simple, after all. :-)