# Transparency in the BMP image format Java

Tags: java, javax.imageio, twelvemonkeys

Is it possible to store a `BufferedImage` with transparency in the BMP image format? With 32 bits per pixel this information should be storable. I also don't need a fine gradation of transparency but only is transparent or not. I want to save the image using Java and `ImageIO`. For this I also use the extensions of `TwelveMonkeys`.

I need to save it in a directly modifiable format because the image is too large for the memory of the creating program and the program assembles the image piece by piece.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487168/writing-a-bmp-with-transparency-using-imageio

Comment: Yes thank you. I have also seen this thread but there is no solution. In the comments it only says that it was implemented by myself. Is there any way to get this implementation?

Comment: Google would be the best place to start

Comment: Note that the bmp form is the most memory costly. **png** does lossless compression. You'll need the RGBA/ARGB with Alpha.

Comment: I added support for BMP with transparency in TwelveMonkeys years ago, I should probably have updated the other thread... However, I find the statements *"I want to save the image using Java and ImageIO"* and *"the image is too large for the memory of the creating program and the program assembles the image piece by piece"* contradicting. Can you elaborate on how you plan on implementing this?